# Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta2 - Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to use an Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 today with new version of `gradle plugin - 3.0.0-beta2`. I added `google()` to repositories clicked Sync, but there is a strange error:

```
Gradle 'X' project refresh failed
    Error:Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

What can cause this error? It appears even when I create a new, empty project. On Gradle plugin 2.3.3 everything works great.

My project `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this on the build script in your build.gradle project file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
dependencies {
    //This should be beta 2 in this case
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4' 
}
```

}

**also you should have this:**

```
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Putting that together you should have something like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then go to the options menu>>>build>>>clean project and then rebuild project.

If that doesn't work then:
1. Open terminal: `./gradlew clean`
2. Quit and restart android studio.